# excel find datetime difference less than certain interval

Tags: excel

I have data like this

| LAST_UPDATE_DATE | CREATION_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 10/9/2021 4:42:46 PM | 10/9/2021 3:25:36 PM |
| 10/13/2021 1:52:12 PM | 10/13/2021 10:53:07 AM |

I want to calculate that whether last_update_date is larger than 24 hours+creation date.
I have already add function like this

```
=TEXT(I2-AE2,"[h]:mm:ss")
```

which I got

| Date_Diff |
| --- |
| 1:17:10 |
| 2:59:05 |

in which case the new column response_in_time
should return

| response_in_time |
| --- |
| F |
| F |

How should I write the formula for new column?

Comment: What is logic to get `F` as response from `Date_Diff`?

Comment: @Harun24HR whether datediff>24:00:00, but I didn't find a good method to write this

Comment: Excel stores datetimes as days and fractions of a day.  So simply: `=(LAST_UPDATE_DATE - CREATION_DATE) > 1` => your desired result.